# Way Cant i import lit HTML from a node website

Tags: node.js, lit-html

Hi on a little project I'm working on trying to learn node , I have a node get request witch read the main page HTML file and then send it,

On the HTML site , I have a script tag ( with type=module),
And at the very beginning of the script im importing the lit- HTML module, yet it seams they the entire script tag isent working, how can I fix it ? 
  The node code :

```
if (req.method === "GET") {     console.log(req.url);   switch (req.url) {  case '/' :      res.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type": "text/html"})        fs.createReadStream("index.html","UTF-8").pipe(res);    break; 

case '/lit-html.js':    var file = fs.readFileSync('lib/lit-html.mjs','UTF-8')  res.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type": "application/javascript"})   res.end(file); break;
```

And this is inside index.html

```
<script type="module" src="localhost:8000/lit-html.js"></script> <script> import {html, render} from 'localhost:8000/lit-html.js';
```

This is in node

```
if (req.method === "GET") {     console.log(req.url);   switch (req.url) {  case '/' :      res.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type": "text/html"})        fs.createReadStream("index.html","UTF-8").pipe(res);    break;

case '/lit-html.js':
var file = fs.readFileSync('lib/lit-html.mjs','UTF-8')
res.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type": "application/javascript"})
res.end(file);
```

break;

And this is inside index.html

```
<script type="module" src="localhost:8000/lit-html.js"></script> <script> import {html, render} from 'localhost:8000/lit-html.js';
```

Comment: Please add a minimal code example of that demostrate the issue.

Comment: The script with _type=module_ means you're loading on the page a [Web Component](https://www.webcomponents.org/) not a simple javascript code.

Comment: Isent it just means I'm loading a js module ? It's not necessary mean a web component to my anderstending, also I don't think it matters...

Comment: You said you have a "script tag", I interpreted that as a new Web Component. That's the reason we need you to public your code in order to understand what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Your web server is trying to map the url request for `lit-html.js` to a file called `lib/lit-html.mjs`

If you installed `lit-html` via `npm`  it would have the file name `lit-html.js` and it would be stored in `node_modules/lit-html/lit-html.js`

As you can see the two don't match.

Check the extension and the location of the file